# Which map projection should be used for preserving coordinates on a 2D image?

Tags: stereographic-projections, map-projections

I have coordinates of a city on earth, say latitude: 57.7072326, longitude: 11.9670171. This is city A. I also have coordinates for another city, called city B.

I want to place a marker on these 2 cities on a 2D image. I know the pixel location of city A, and I also know the pixel location of city B.

Now, I get coordinates for a third city, called city C. I do not know the pixel locations of this city, but as I know the pixel locations of 2 other cities, and I can find the relation between the coordinates of city C with A & B, I should be able to find the pixel location of city C. However, always when I do this, my locations are skewed toward either projecting a little bit too far away, and sometimes a little bit too near. What my guess is, that it has to do with the map projection, for example if I am drawing the markers on a Mercator projection, or if it is any other projection.

What my question is, which projection will preserve linearity of coordinates? Is this even possible? A restriction that probably makes this easier is that I am only placing markers on the country of Sweden, and hence there is not a big difference in the coordinate values between the cities (for example, the latitude is around 57 - 65, and longitude is between 11 - 23 for all the cities).

Comment: Just to make sure I understand; you have x-y coordinates (under some projection) for $A$ and $B$ as well as lat/longs for $A$ and $B$ and you have the lat/long for $C$ and you want x-y coordinates for $C$? If that's right, then I don't think linear interpolation will give a very good answer for any projection unless $A$, $B$ and $C$ are very close. A stereographic projection based on a point of tangency near the centre of your map of Sweden will probably be your best bet. Doesn't your source of map data give you a way of converting x-y to lat/long?

Comment: @RobArthan That is exactly what I was wondering, spot on! Yes, seems like linear interpolation is not that nice. Unfortunately, I get my coordinates from a python script that  searches for a city, and then I want to plot these on a whole separate image, not connected to the original source of map data. I am however confused in which way such a stereographic projection would be done. I tried to adjust the directional "units" for x and y depending on which latitude the city was, but that was just horrible and utterly painful

Comment: I think you need to find out more about how your data sources model positions.  The formulas for converting lat/long to x-y and back aren't too complicated for the projections that are commonly used, but you you need to know what they are.

Comment: @RobArthan Maybe I should add that I am manually setting the x-y coordinates of A and B, so those I know exactly how I am getting. Maybe I should try some projection formula as you said, I'll give it a go!